# How can I use and clone both github and aws (CodeCommit) repos on the same machine?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github

How can I set up my system so I can clone from both sources - github and aws CodeCommit - without making changes to switch between them each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create or edit a `~/.ssh/config` file

Make the contents be:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User APKAS2GIPODK7YOUR-ID 
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa

Host github.com
  User your_github_username
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I am assuming you already have generated your github ssh keys as `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`
Generate your aws keys as follows to create the `codecommit_rsa` files, i.e. different files from your github `id_rsa` files

```
$ ssh-keygen                                                                                                                                   
Generating public/private rsa key pair.                                                                                                        
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/durrantm/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/durrantm/.ssh/codecommit_rsa     

#
# **NOTE** As shown, change above filename from id_rsa to codecommit_rsa !!! 
# This avoids over-writing your github id_rsa keys (so you can have both)
# So don't just press return for defaults !!!                                     
#

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):                                                                                                    
Enter same passphrase again:                                                                                                                   
Your identification has been saved in /home/durrantm/.ssh/codecommit_rsa.                                                                      
Your public key has been saved in /home/durrantm/.ssh/codecommit_rsa.pub.
```

Now I can clone either repo

```
$ git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/HellowBlueGreenWorld
Cloning into 'HellowBlueGreenWorld'...
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), 759 bytes | 759.00 KiB/s, done.
...


$ git clone git@github.com:durrantm/setups.git
Cloning into 'setups'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
...
Receiving objects: 100% (1739/1739), 1.21 MiB | 4.52 MiB/s, done.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer aliasing AWS codecommit repos, because I can't use multiple AWS accounts with just specifying Host.

My ~/.ssh/config file(where AWS account administrator has RW access, reader has R access):

```
# AWS - administrator
Host git-aws-administrator
  Hostname git-codecommit.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com 
  User ABCDEFGHIJK
  IdentityFile /Users/(username)/.ssh/id_rsa
# AWS - reader
Host git-aws-reader
  Hostname git-codecommit.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com 
  User 123456789
  IdentityFile /Users/(username)/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And when you clone your codecommit repository as administrator account, you clone with `git clone ssh://git-aws-administrator/v1/repos/(reponame)` command. When you clone non-codecommit repository, you just clone it as usual.

Comment: Nice!  Would specifying two aws entries with same host but different User for each help with that?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant It is similar to your answer, but it also solves switching between codecommit repos so I thought it would be helpful if someone wants to switch between github and multiple codecommit repos with several accounts.

Comment: The tedious part of this solution is that you can't assign all region as asterisk. For example, when you want to clone repo A as admin in ap-northeast-1 region and repo B as admin in ap-northeast-2 region, you have to edit your ~/.ssh/config and add two entries with different region.

Comment: ah yeah, that's annoying.  repo shouldn't care about region like that